# clearTimeout on keypress when typing

Tags: jquery

I'm building an autosuggest for a cities input, but the problem is that when I type "Boston" for example, it will load results for "Boston", but then replace those with results for "Bost", and then "B" because it takes the longest to load. I'm trying to cancel the request, but it doesn't work. I'm trying to set a timeout so it only loads when the user is done typing, but it doesn't stop it from loading earlier variants like "B" either.

```
var timer;
    $('#city').keyup(function(event) {
        clearTimeout(timer); // not working
        var c = $('#country').val(),
            v = $('#city').val(),
            e = $('.city-suggest');
        if(v.length > 0) {
            var timer = setTimeout(function() {
                e.html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>').show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '../-parse/check-city.php?c='+c+'&v='+v,
                    success: function(data) {
                        e.html(data);
                    }
                });
            }, 2500);
        } else {
            $('.city-suggest').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You're setting a new `var timer` into the scope of the keyup function, so you're not using the one in the global scope. In order to use the clearTimeOut(), remove the `var` while defining the timeout function

Comment: [Detect when user type done](https://sdtuts.com/detect-when-user-type-done/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting a new `var timer` into the scope of the keyup function, so you're not using the one in the global scope. In order to use the clearTimeout(), remove the `var` while defining the timeout function

```js
var timer;
    $('#city').keyup(function(event) {
        clearTimeout(timer); // now working
        var c = $('#country').val(),
            v = $('#city').val(),
            e = $('.city-suggest');
        if(v.length > 0) {
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                e.html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>').show();
                e.html('hello World');
                
            }, 2500);
        } else {
            $('.city-suggest').hide();
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="country" type="text" value="Country"/>
<input id="city" type="text"/>
<span class="city-suggest"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that setTimeout's don't work well over multiple lines.

```
var timer;
$('#city').keyup(function(event) {
clearTimeout(timer); // not working
var c = $('#country').val(),
var v = $('#city').val(),
var e = $('.city-suggest');
if(v.length > 0) {
    var timer = setTimeout(function(){e.html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>').show();$.ajax({url: '../-parse/check-city.php?c='+c+'&v='+v,success: function(data) {e.html(data);}});}, 2500);
} else {
    $('.city-suggest').hide();
}
});
```

Also, if you want it to be easier to read the code, this should work:

```
var c = '';
var v = '';
var e = '';
var timer;
$('#city').keyup(function(event) {
    clearTimeout(timer); // not working
        c = $('#country').val(),
        v = $('#city').val(),
        e = $('.city-suggest');
    if(v.length > 0) {
        var timer = setTimeout(function(){City()}, 2500);
    } else {
    $('.city-suggest').hide();
}
});
function City(){
    e.html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: '../-parse/check-city.php?c='+c+'&v='+v,success: function(data){e.html(data);}
});
}
```